# How to resolve Dynamic URLs dependencies through Service worker?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, sw-precache, sw-toolbox

Though I am familiar with `Sw-precache` and `Sw-toolbox` libraries, Still puzzle on how to cater Dynamic Dependencies while building Progressive Web App using Angular.

I have pre-cached bundle.js, bundle.css and some static templates for my application using Sw-precache build process. (Assume all my templates (.html files) are dependent on bundle.js and bundle.css)

1. What if I update my template which is not pre-cached ? How do I ensure Updation of bundle.js/css in conjunction with my template.
2. What if I update my template which is already pre-cached. Does it always update in conjunction with pre-cached bundle.js/css files.
3. Last use case, When my template is already pre-cached but it has some inline script with src attribute and this script file is not cached anywhere. Assume I made some changes in template as well as script file. What caching approach should I follow to ensure Updation of template file in conjunction with script file.

We are not following pure App-shell architecture, It's like Single Page App designed using Angular.js

Answer (score 1):

Sw-Precache will update for the file changes, generate a new service worker and when you deploy updates to bundle js or css, you should be deploying your new Sw-Precache generated service worker as well.

Comment: Service worker has its own life cycle to update stuff..What if templates, which is not precached, fetched from network and it's dependent CSS/js(preached) is not updated at that time due to sone activate event not triggered.? Did u get me?

Comment: well if you server the html page, it won't request those new assets until the service worker is updated which updates the html page which then pulls in the latest assets.

If you want to manage dynamic content then you should look at the following in sw-precache: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#runtimecaching-arrayobject

Answer (score 0):

Just as a general idea, hash all the resources you're precaching and the perform a hash of hashes and include this digest in the service worker so when one of the dependencies change, the digest will change and your service worker will update triggering a new installation event. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah it make sense. But I'm worried about what if my templates are not cached and its associated js/css is pre-cached. Then there will be a case when any changes made to templates , its assoicated js/css will not get picked with immediate effect. ?

Comment: Does the template alteration change your bundles in any way? If so, the hashes for your bundles will change and your service worker will update. If not, you should add the hash of your templates to the hash of hashes.